# Dynamically added Twitter Bootstrap popover with <br> does not break lines

Tags: ajax, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a large paginated table. Each row shows a client with it's information. I use an AJAX call to check if there are notes for a client.

If there is a note for a client an icon gets added. It is added as inner html of a  which is merely a placeholder just for this notification icon. When hovering the icon shows it shows the available notes in a twitter bootstrap popover.

It works fine except the line breaks `<br>` or `<br />` don't actually break the line but show as regular text in the popover. It might be due to the fact they are added after page load since it has always worked for my static popovers.

Through search I found that `html : true` must be passed but it doesn't help. How can get html line breaks to render in a popover which the popover was added dynamically?

The placeholder for the note has the following markup:

```
<span class="notitieIndicatie" id="519de1b978b55"></span>
```

The javascript with the ajax loading looks is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">        
$(document).ready(function()
{        
    function getMessageAjax(uniqid)
    {
        var notes = "";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data:
            {
                action: 'getNotes',
                uniqid: uniqid,
                cache: false
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                if (data != 'NULL')
                {
                    var theValues = $.parseJSON(data);                        
                    $.each(theValues, function(key, value)
                    {
                        notes += '&bull;'+value['n_kort']+'<br>';
                    });                        
                    var popover = '<img src="images/icons/icon-info.gif" class="notepopover" data-content="'+notes+'" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="" />';
                    $('#'+uniqid).html(popover);                        
                    $('body').popover({
                        selector: '.notepopover',
                        trigger: "hover",
                        html : true
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    $('.notitieIndicatie').each(function(i, obj) {        
        getMessageAjax(this.id);
    });

});
```

Comment: where are you inserting `<br>`? I can't find it in your code

Comment: in the `each` loop like so: `notes += '&bull;'+value['n_kort']+'<br>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to avoid using `data-content` but instead pass the html string to the popover call as a value in `content`

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function getMessageAjax(uniqid)
    {
        var notes = "";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data:
            {
                action: 'getNotes',
                uniqid: uniqid,
                cache: false
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                if (data != 'NULL')
                {
                    var theValues = $.parseJSON(data);

                    var notesHTML = '<ul>';
                    $.each(theValues, function(key, value)
                    {
                        notesHTML += '<li>'+value['n_kort']+'</li>';
                    });
                    notesHTML += '</ul>';

                    var html = $('<img src="images/icons/icon-info.gif" class="notepopover" />');
                    $('#'+uniqid).append(html);

                    html.popover({
                        placement: "bottom",
                        trigger: "hover",
                        content: notesHTML,
                        html : true
                    });


                }
            }
        });
    }

    $('.notitieIndicatie').each(function(i, obj) {
        getMessageAjax(this.id);
    });

});
```